# GPL in Plugin for a open source application

Tags: closed-source, plugins

I am trying to do a feasibility study for doing a plugin that implements a 2D geometry solver in various programs. The solver is GPL v3. Some of the programs are GPL themselves but some are not, like Illustrator.

So if:

- My plugin is distributed online, not as a part of a commercial application
- My source is also distributed online, and complies with GPL Licencing
- But you can not actually run said plugin without the commercial application as its a plugin for it.

Is this ok?

Comment: Relevant GPL FAQ: [Can I apply the GPL when writing a plug-in for a nonfree program?](https://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-faq.en.html#GPLPluginsInNF)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot use the GNU GPL in a plugin for a non-GPL program.

However, you can use the GNU LGPL license.

Comment: Well I can but i cant distribute it to others